# Using venkman in my xul application

Tags: firefox, xul, venkman

I've tried to follow [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_a_XULRunner_Application#Venkman) steps to get venkman in my xul application:

1. Get Venkman from addons.mozilla.org To download the package, right-click the install link and save the package locally. (got the newest version).
2. Create a directory /distribution/bundles/venkman. Unzip the package into that directory.
3. Add `<script src="chrome://venkman/content/venkman-overlay.js" />` to one of your XUL windows.
4. Add UI to open Venkman to your window (it could be a menu item or a toolbar button). Make it call start_venkman() when activated.

Not sure where to create the distribution directory, I've tried in the same directory as my application.ini in chrome and in chrome/content but when I try to include the script as in step 3 I get:

```
No chrome package registered for chrome://venkman/content/venkman-overlay.js
```

And step 4 gives me:

```
Error: ReferenceError: start_venkman is not defined
```

I start my application using the following command:

```
firefox.exe --app application.ini -jsconsole
```

Changed the BuildID in my application.ini a couple of times but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Those instructions are for using XULRunner.  Do you get the same error when using that instead of the Firefox binary?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've created the distribution directory in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox` and now I don't get the `No chrome package registered for chrome://venkman/content/venkman-overlay.js` but when trying to open the venkman window when I click a button I still get: `Error: ReferenceError: start_venkman is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created the directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\bundles` and copied the venkman directory in there.

In my xul window I added:

```
<script src="test.js" />
<button label="Press Me"
    oncommand="start_venkman();"/>
```

The content of test.js is:

```
function toOpenWindowByType(inType, uri) {
  var winopts = "chrome,extrachrome,menubar,resizable,scrollbars,status,toolbar";
  window.open(uri, "_blank", winopts);
}
```

When I click the button the Venkman window opens.